# How to find hosting company via IP?

Tags: hosting

I need to update a website of my client.
The original developer is not contactable now.
And my client doesn't have any information about the hosting company.
The domain is registered thru Network Solutions.

All we have is the IP address.
And I looked it up at http://www.robtex.com/ip/168.143.23.16.html#ip .
It says "NTTC-GIN-AS NTT Communications Global IP Network".
I contacted NTT and they said that they are not hosting the site.

In this case, how do we find the hosting company?
By the way, changing hosting company is not the option right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to figure out who NTT's customer is who has the IP in that block.  They should be the host.  I suggest this wouldn't be very easy.

However, luckily, they provide a WHOIS referral (use the whois command on any unix box).  This line appears:

```
network:Org-Name:Verio Web Hosting (SME)
```

Comment: A `traceroute` would have worked too. In my trace, the second-to-last hop was `po-1.c20.stngva01.us.wh.verio.net`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like its hosted by Verio (http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/).

I've had some past experience with that host.  If you can dump them you should!

Answer (score 1):

For this particualar ip address, I generally find out from ARIN who manages the address space from here:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml

And in this case its arin, and Arin does say NTT looks after it, I suggest the person you spoke to was mistaken, they are the abuse, and other contacts.
http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-168-143-0-0-1/pft

Comment: Delegations are important.

Answer (score -2):

You haven't tried doing a lookup on the domain name, seeing what the nameservers are and going from there, have you? ;) Anyway, that site is using WORLDNIC name servers, therefore it seems to be NETSOL hosting - http://www.networksolutions.com/. Hopefully, I'm correct.

Comment: I already asked NetSol and they said that they are not hosting it.

Comment: The name servers have nothing to do with where the actual server and site sit, just who answers and responds to DNS requests.